# Automating distributed system testing with multiple browser windows

Tags: selenium, websocket, distributed

I'm building a distributed system with websockets. Browser clients can connect to each other directly or to a central server. I would like to test a few distributed use cases end-to-end.

Example 1:

- Open Browser A and connect to my site
- Open Browser B and connect to my site
- Browser A sends a chat message to Browser B
- Confirm that Browser B received the message

Example 2:

- Open Browser A and connect to my site
- Open Browser B and connect to my site
- Browser A sends a chat message to Browser B
- On Browser B, a "disconnect" button is clicked
- Confirm that Browser B does not receive the message
- On Browser B, a "reconnect" button is clicked
- Confirm that Browser A received the message

How can I do this? I've seen selenium running in parallel, but I haven't seen anything that allows you to coordinate the interaction between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your test can open many webdriver instances.

If you open 2 instances in your test, one can represent browser A and the other browser B.

Call methods on these objects to simulate the scenario you discuss in your post.

To achieve this you need to use RemoteWebDriver. If all hosted locally, you will get two unconnected browsers on your computer. If you use a Grid, then you will get 2 browsers somewhere on your grid, probably on different machines.

If you want complete control, you could just start Selenium instances on two remote machines and use these hard coded machine names for A and B. In this scenario there would be no Grid.

Word of warning though. If you try to host all browsers locally, you cannot use IE as multiple IE all share common data where as Chrome are completely separate